# Discord.js: Mute multiple users at once

Tags: javascript, multithreading, discord, discord.js, mute

I'm currently developing a discord bot that can mute/deafen part of a voice chat. It works, but I'm running into some issues. When the bot tries to mute a big group of players, they get muted one by one. When one of the players has a slower internet connection, all the players below them have to wait until that player gets muted. This means a mute/unmute can take up to 10 seconds for 5 players, which is too long for the purpose I'm using it for.

simplified code of the muting/deafening process:

```
this.players.forEach(player => {
  // If player belongs to group that has to be muted
  if ([condition]) {
    // Mute and undeafen player
    player.voice.setMute(true)
    player.voice.setDeaf(false)
  }
})
```

(where 'players' is an array with GuildMember objects)

My question is, is there a way to speed up this process? My solution would be to mute all players independently, but I have no idea how to implement this. I am thinking of using multithreading, but I'm not sure if this would even solve the problem, and I don't know how Javascript and Discord.js handle multithreading because I'm fairly new to JS. So, does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think whether multiple processes are slow or not is depend on your bot server and your discord server(your bot is in). Not your user's network.
And basically js is synchronous, your process will be done at the almost same time.
(If you want async tasks, you can do it with `then`, `Promise` and `async await`.)

Relieve worries little.

Thanks.